# Is Bs(1,-1) linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I would like to prove that the Baumslag-Solitar group $BS(1,-1)=\langle a,b| bab^{-1}=a^{-1}\rangle$ is embeddable in $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ for some nonnegative integer $n.$ So i tried to find two matrices $A$ and $B$ of infinite order in $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $BAB^{-1}=B^{-1}.$ I have a problem. I saw that the invertible matrices which are conjugated to their inverses are the ones which could be written as a product of involutions. Doesn't that mean such matrices have finite order since an involution is an element of order 2? That would be a contradiction since $a$ and $b$ have infinite order. Could somebody help me please? By advance thank you.

Comment: Why should a product of involutions have finite order?

Comment: I thought it was the case because I thought the product of elements of finite order has finite order too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a\to\left( \begin{array}{rrr}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right),$
$b\to\left( \begin{array}{rrr}1&0&1\\0&-1&0\\0&0&1\end{array}\right).$

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see your answer. I have a question. How do I prove that the matrices below have no other relation but $BAB^{-1}$ where $A$ and $B$ are the matrices below.

Comment: Using the relation $bab^{-1}=a^{-1}$, show that every element of ${\rm BS}(1,-1)$ can be written as $a^ib^j$ with $i,j \in {\mathbb Z}$. It is not hard to show that the eleemnts $A^iB^j$ are all distinct. The isomorphism follows.

Comment: I managed to prove thatevery element of $BS(1,-1)$ can be written as $a^ib^j$ with $i,j\in\mathbb{Z}.$ To prove the elements $A^iB^j$ are all distinct for $i,j\neq0,$ I suppose there exist $i',j'\in\mathbb{Z}$ nonzero such that $A^iB^j=A^{i'}B^{j'}$ i.e. $A^{i-i'}=B^{j'-j}.$ Do I have to explicit the $n$-th powers of $A$ and $B$ to conclude?

Comment: The first row of $A^iB^j$ is $(1\ \pm i \ j)$.